# What does the $v$ term in the proper time equation represent exactly?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, time, velocity

I'm trying to intuitively understand proper time which is defined as the time that is always measured in a moving observer’s or particle's rest frame and is given by the equation.

$\Delta\tau = \sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}}\Delta t$, where $\Delta t$ is the coordinate time.

As such, what does the v term in the proper time equation represent exactly? Moreover, what exactly is the difference between proper and coordinate time?

Answer (score 4):

> I'm trying to intuitively understand proper time which is defined as the time that is always measured in a moving observer’s or particle's rest frame

It is better to define proper time as the time measured by a given clock. For example the [Proper time Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_time) definition is:

"In relativity, proper time (from Latin, meaning own time) along a timelike world line is defined as the time as measured by a clock following that line."

This is better because it does not talk about reference frames. Since proper time is an invariant quantity it is better to define it explicitly in terms of observer-independent concepts. One other thing that is good about this definition is that it explicitly mentions the concept of a worldline. Proper time is a quantity defined along a specified timelike worldline.

> As such, what does the v term in the proper time equation represent exactly?

The $v$ represents the velocity of the clock in any given inertial frame. The $\Delta t$ is the coordinate time in that same inertial frame.

> Moreover, what exactly is the difference between proper and coordinate time?

There are many differences. In my opinion the most important differences are these:

- The domain: coordinate time is defined over all of spacetime while
  proper time is only defined on the given worldline. Proper time can be equal to coordinate time on the given worldline, but even then they are distinct concepts since coordinate time is defined on events where proper time is not. This is another reason why the definition of proper time in terms of a rest frame is not a good definition. Such a definition obscures this difference.
- Simultaneity: coordinate time defines a notion of the simultaneity of two distant events while proper time does not establish any relationship between events not on the given worldline
- Invariance: coordinate time clearly depends on the coordinates while proper time is invariant under any arbitrary coordinate transformation (however the formula you cited is only for inertial coordinates)
- Causality: the ordering established by proper time is a causal order, events with smaller proper time can cause events with larger proper time, while coordinate time is not a causal order, there are events with smaller coordinate time that cannot cause other events with larger coordinate time.

Comment: 1. "In relativity, proper time (from Latin, meaning own time) along a timelike world line is defined as the time as measured by a clock following that line." - is the time that is being measured on this clock being by someone traveling with the clock or someone externally looking at the clock? 2."The v represents the velocity of the clock in any given inertial frame." - Since all motion is relative and thus v can take on different values, then how can proper time be invariant if proper time takes on different values depending on relative motion?

Comment: @AnthonySmith “is the time that is being measured on this clock being by someone traveling with the clock or someone externally looking at the clock?” it doesn’t matter, it is invariant, everyone agrees on what a clock reads at any given event. “how can proper time be invariant if proper time takes on different values depending on relative motion?” it doesn’t take on different values, that is what invariant means.

Comment: This is the crux of my confusion. One on hand if v represents the velocity of the clock in any given inertial frame. Then $\Delta\tau = \sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}}\Delta t$. So far, no problem. However, if I'm moving with the particle/clock then v=0, thus $\Delta\tau = \sqrt{1 - \frac{0^2}{c^2}}\Delta t = \Delta t$. These are not the same, at face value it appears that proper time will have two different values. Please help me rectify this confusion. - Thanks

Comment: @AnthonySmith you seem to be forgetting that $\Delta t$ varies in different frames too. $v$ varies between frames and so does $\Delta t$ such that $\Delta \tau$ is invariant

Comment: I hadn't considered that $\Delta t$ varies, can you demonstrate this in an equation, or at the very least point me in the right direction where I can see it for myself? - Thanks

Comment: @AnthonySmith sure. See: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation

Comment: So, one thought, time dilation is the ratio of coordinate time and proper time. Hence me be stationary coordinate time is what I would measure looking at my own clock and proper time is the time measured on the clock of the moving particle. Therefore, coordinate time (my measured time) cannot be varying, and coordinate time is what used in the proper time equation; therefore, coordinate time cannot be varying in the proper time equation in order for me to make correct use of the time dilation equation. No?

Comment: @AnthonySmith No. But I am not willing to continue the discussion here. We are getting the “extended discussion” warning. It seems like you want a discussion format more than a Q&A format. I recommend physicsforums.com where I am also active

Answer (score 2):

Here's a pictorial answer. The moving observer has the worldline in blue. The proper time interval $\Delta\tau$ (red angled line) expresses length along that worldline. It's a combination of the coordinate spatial interval $\Delta x$ and the coordinate time interval $\Delta t$ essentially by the Pythagorean theorem, just with a negative sign due to the Lorentzian [metric signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_signature).

[image: Spacetime diagram]

For fun I also included the hyperbolic angle $w$ ([rapidity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapidity)) in green.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an unclear way to look at. Since, based on the equation, you are comparing 2 time differences among 3 events.

Let's say the 1st even is the start. In the rest frame ($S$):

$$E_0=(ct=0,x=0)$$

which the moving observer ($S'$) records as

$$E'_0=(ct'=0,x'=0) $$

The next event is

$$E_1=(c\Delta\tau, 0)$$

the end of the interval, in $S$. $S$ sees the moving observer at another event:

$$E_2=(c\Delta\tau, v\Delta\tau)$$

So $E_1$ and $E_2$ are simultaneous for $S$.

In $S'$:

$$E'_2 = (c\Delta t, 0) $$

So $S$ sees $S'$'s clock ticking slower, and $E_1$ and $E_2$ are not simultaneous in $S'$.  If you just use abstract $\Delta$'s, confusion will result, as you'll forget which hyperplane of simultaneity (defined by equal coordinate time in a reference frame) by which you are comparing.

BTW: Dale's answer is entirely correct, but complementary to mine.